# Using useListController inside ListContextProvider doesn't provide the data

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` and I am encountering the Problem that `useListController` does not provide any data inside `ListContextProvider` even though `useListContext` does.

```js
  const query = useQuery({
    type: 'getList',
    resource: 'dashboard/summary',
    payload: {
      pagination: { page, perPage },
      sort: { field: 'createdAt', order: 'DESC' },
      filter
    },
  });
  // more code ....
  return (
      <ListContextProvider
        value={{
          ...query,
          setPage,
          basePath,
          data: keyBy(query.data, 'id'),
          ids: query.data.map(({ id }) => id),
          currentSort: { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' },
          selectedIds: [],
          resource,
          page,
          perPage,
          setFilters
        }}
      >
        <SummaryList onSearch={onSearch} filter={filter} />
      </ListContextProvider>
  );
```

Inside `SummaryList`

```js
  const context = useListContext();
  const cp = useListController(context);
  console.log(context);
  console.log(cp);
```

The controller Object

```json
basePath: "/dashboard/summary"
currentSort: Object { field: "id", order: "ASC" }
data: Object {  }
defaultTitle: "Dashboard/summaries"
displayedFilters: Object {  }
error: null
exporter: function defaultExporter(data, _, __, resource)
filter: undefined
filterValues: Object {  }
hasCreate: undefined
hideFilter: function hideFilter(filterName)​
ids: Array []
loaded: true
loading: false
onSelect: function select(newIds)​
onToggleItem: function toggle(id)​
onUnselectItems: function clearSelection()
page: 1
perPage: 10
resource: "dashboard/summary"
selectedIds: Array []
setFilters: function setFilters(filter, displayedFilters, debounce)​
setPage: function setPage(newPage)​
setPerPage: function setPerPage(newPerPage)​
setSort: function setSort(sort, order)​
showFilter: function showFilter(filterName, defaultValue)
total: undefined
```

The context Object

```json
{
  "data": {
  // the data which I omitted
  },
  "total": 4,
  "loading": false,
  "loaded": true,
  "basePath": "/dashboard/summary",
  "ids": [
    "2021-05-01",
    "2021-05-02",
    "2021-05-03",
    "2021-05-04"
  ],
  "currentSort": {
    "field": "id",
    "order": "ASC"
  },
  "selectedIds": [],
  "resource": "dashboard/summary",
  "page": 1,
  "perPage": 10
}
```

How am I supposed to use `useListController` ?

Answer (score 1):

`useListController` takes the List props (and location parameters), uses it to fetch data from the dataProvider, and passes it to the ListContext.

By calling useListContext(), you're accessing the values and callbacks built by `useListController`.

In your example, you're building the ListContext by hand, so you don't need `useListController` at all.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I didnt see it in the docs but I never saw that mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Now that Ive reread the documentation it does seem kind of obvious where the ListBase Component is explained.